# Why is the exception message being return to the client when I override it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, actionresult

Short Question: Why is additional exception text being included with one Action when they are all handled in a generic way that should prevent it?

Explanation: I have some generic error handling code in my mvc.net 4 application. Any unhandled exceptions are logged and a generic message is returned as part of the result. I do this by creating a base controller class that overrides OnException. It looks similar to this.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext){

  ...//Some logging stuff

   filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { Message = "An error has occured. If you continue to experience this issue, please contact an administrator.", success = false },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

        };
}
```

That should return a JSON object that contains a generic error message. The responseText looks like

```
"{ Message = "An error has occured. If you continue to experience this issue, please contact an   administrator.", success = false }"
```

When that message is returned, it is handled by a generic javascript function:

```
function HandleServerError(response) {
   var message = JSON.parse(response.responseText).Message;
   ShowMessage(message, true);
   HideProgress();
}
```

In most cases this works nicely. For example, I have a method that uses ajax to save some data on the server and receives a JSON message in return.

```
function ChangeSecurityStatus(securityID, isActive) {
ShowProgress();

$.ajax({
    url: "SetSecurityIsActiveStatus",
    data: { "securityID": securityID, "isActive": isActive },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        ShowMessage(result.Message);
        HideProgress();
    }
});
```

}

SetSecurityIsActiveStatus is a JsonResult that is currently set to automatically throw an exception with the message "Its Broken!". When it fails, it goes in to the generic error handler client side.

There is another ajax call that seems to work differently. It looks like this:

```
function SetStatus(action, id, status) {

ShowProgress();
$.ajax({
    url: "SetSecurityContentIsActiveStatus",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "id": id, "status": status },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result)
            ShowMessage("Action is successfully saved.");
        else
            ShowMessage("There is an issue saving your action.", true);
    },
    complete: function (request, textStatus) {
        HideProgress();
    }
});
```

}

SetSecurityContentIsActiveStatus is a JsonResult that is currently set to automatically throw an exception with the message "Its Broken!". When I make this request, the response I get back is this

```
   "Its Broken!{ Message = "An error has occured. If you continue to experience this issue, please contact an   administrator.", success = false }"
```

That isn't a valid json string and throws an error when I call JSON.parse. It runs through the OnException override correctly and the generic message is getting passed to the client, but the actual exception is being passed as well.

I cant really tell a difference between the 2 ajax calls and why they would return different results.

Comment: How you are invoking DoSomething() action method? Ajax?

Comment: Yes, using jquery ajax. I might have to post some more details or change the question because I may not have described the problem correctly.

Comment: Actually I've tried above scenario,but in both cases it's returning valid json reslut only

Comment: Yeah I think it might not have anything to do with the ActionResult. Im going to change the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of the controllers had a custom attribute that handled errors. It would handle errors on top of my base controller, so both messages were being passed.